# Linking two tables with different types on Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, db2

I want to link two tables on Crystal Reports XI and I am using DB2 however their primary keys are different types.
One is an Integer the other is Varchar, how can I link them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how can you link integer and varchar...how are you implementing are you directly linking tables are using query?

Comment: Well its through Crystal so I want to find a way to link the two if it was through query I would write ID_KEY = CAST(DETAIL_LINE_ID AS VARCHAR(7))

Comment: One way is you can create a view and link both table and view

Comment: I created a view with all my data I need, I am using a db2 server can you help me create a view? I will post the query I have that I need to be in view. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: SELECT T.CREATED_TIME, T.CREATED_BY, T.BILL_NUMBER, ORIGCITY, ORIGPROV, DESTCITY, DESTPROV, DISTANCE, TOTAL_PAY_FUNC_AMT, 
(SELECT VARCHAR(THE_NOTE,255) FROM NOTES WHERE ID_KEY = CAST(T.DETAIL_LINE_ID AS VARCHAR(7)) AND NOTE_TYPE = 'B') NOTE
FROM TLORDER T, DRIVERPAY D
WHERE T.DETAIL_LINE_ID = D.DETAIL_LINE_ID 
AND CUSTOMER = 'ATLANTA' 
AND T.CREATED_BY <> 'ATLANTA'
AND T.CREATED_TIME >= CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 7 DAYS

Answer (score 0):

I created a view and used that to display my data on excel.